# publish laravel 5.5 app on amazon aws ec2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deploy laravel app on amazon aws but it's not working. When i visit url it says 'This site can’t be reached'. Can anybody help me solve the issue?
I have already uploaded code and setup database on amazon aws ec2. Also changed DocumentRoot "/var/www/public" in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `composer install` ? This could be the issue. Also, have you checked your Apache for enabling ReWrite? Try this for Apache `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

If all that fails, try changing permissions for Laravel Files. The following commands will work for you:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/ bootstrap/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Failure point with the info you've given thus far could be in any number of places.  So start with the basics and go from there.

First thing I would do is see if your requests are actually getting to the server.   If you can ssh in to the server and take a look at your access logs, that's a start so you can make sure it is at least getting that far.

Then you can look further from there.   Check error logs, etc.